# STOMP header on @MessageMapping return

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket

In my Spring Boot 1.5 application with Spring Websocket, I'd like to set a custom STOMP header on the return value of a `@MessageMapping` method, but I don't know how to do this. For example:

```
@Controller
public class ChannelController {

    @MessageMapping("/books/{id}")
    public Book receive(@DestinationVariable("id") Long bookId) {
        return findBook(bookId);
    }

    private Book findBook(Long bookId) {
        return //...
    }
}
```

When `receive` is triggered from a client's `STOMP SEND`, I'd like the `STOMP MESSAGE` reply frame with the book body to have a custom header: `message-type:BOOK` like this:

```
MESSAGE
message-type:BOOK
destination:/topic/books/1
content-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
subscription:sub-0
message-id:0-7
content-length:1868

{ 
  "createdDate" : "2017-08-10T10:40:39.256", 
  "lastModifiedDate" : "2017-08-10T10:42:57.976", 
  "id" : 1, 
  "name" : "The big book", 
  "description" : null 
}
^@
```

How do I set a STOMP header for the reply return value in a `@MessageMapping`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the return value signature is not important, you can use `SimpMessagingTemplate` as @Shchipunov noted in the comments to his answer:

```
@Controller
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ChannelController {

    private final SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate; 

    @MessageMapping("/books/{id}")
    public void receive(@DestinationVariable("id") Long bookId, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor accessor ) {
        accessor.setHeader("message-type", "BOOK");

        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(
            "/topic/books/" + bookId, findBook(bookId), accessor.toMap()
        );
    }

    private Book findBook(Long bookId) {
        return //...
    }
}
```

which does correctly serialize to the MESSAGE frame in the question.

Comment: This does not answer the question, but I'll accept this answer until an answer which solves the return value question is provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
@MessageMapping("/books/{id}")
public GenericMessage<Book> receive(@DestinationVariable("id") Long bookId) {
    Map<String, List<String>> nativeHeaders = new HashMap<>();
    nativeHeaders.put("message-type", Collections.singletonList("BOOK"));

    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put(NativeMessageHeaderAccessor.NATIVE_HEADERS, nativeHeaders);

    return new GenericMessage<Book>(findBook(bookId), headers);
}
```

Comment: Curiously, this serializes incorrectly to:
`<<< MESSAGE
destination:/topic/books/1
content-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
subscription:sub-1
message-id:0-8
content-length:489

{
  "payload" : {
    "createdDate" : "2017-08-10T10:40:39.256",
    "lastModifiedDate" : "2017-08-10T10:42:57.976",
    "id" : 471,
    "name" : "The big book",
    "description" : null
  },
  "headers" : {
    "nativeHeaders" : {
      "message-type" : [ "BOOK" ]
    },
    "id" : "7596b750-433e-c0b6-95b2-afd9bb9cbfbf",
    "timestamp" : 1502383378174
  }
}` instead of (see next comment):

Comment: `<<< MESSAGE
message-type:BOOK
destination:/topic/books/1
content-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
subscription:sub-1
message-id:0-8
content-length:489

{
    "createdDate" : "2017-08-10T10:40:39.256",
    "lastModifiedDate" : "2017-08-10T10:42:57.976",
    "id" : 471,
    "name" : "The big book",
    "description" : null
}`

Comment: From Chrome console, it's apparent it's incorrectly serializing `payload` and `headers` to the message payload instead of adding the headers to STOMP message headers and shipping the payload within the body of the STOMP message.

Comment: You can try another solution: inject SimpMessagingTemplate instance and use its "convertAndSend(destination, payload, headers)" method

Comment: Also consider using of SimpMessageHeaderAccessor for the same purpose